# How to import pdf image with different color?

Tags: graphics

I'd like to import a pdf illustrating manifold like [this](http://kahrstrom.com/mathematics/images/manifold5-1.pdf). And I'm using a dark background in beamer, is there any way to change the color of the lines from black to white? Since I've used the codes

> \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
>   \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
>   \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
>   \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=white}
>   \setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=white}

and some of the lines could be changed to white ones like this

[image]

So I'm wondering if there're some method to change this picture totally to white. Since I've only basic knowledge of beamer and latex, this may be a silly question. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? I'm confused: how did you get from the linked PDF to the screenshot you've shown here? And why doesn't whatever you did to make part of the included image white work for all of ti?